# How to select unique records from the list of columns where we need to secure records with certain pair?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I need help with a query in MySQL for the following problem.

Here is my table. We have Name of people with mType resembling with the type of member (mType). Members have pair with mType P & S. Some members can have S along side P, some doesn't. House Number is unique for all P records such that P record following by S record will have same houseNo. If we consider P as parent and S as son, both Parent & Son lives in a same house thus have same houseNo. We need to pull out all records with P & S pair or if P doesn't have S, with records added into the table in latest date order.

Here one of the HouseNo is showing twice in the table, so we need to choose only the record with lastest date for such records and rest of the unique records.

```
mType | mindex    | HouseNo  |     date     |   Name
---------------------------------------------------
  P    |    1     |  111     |  2022-02-10  |  Addy
  S    |    1     |  111     |  2022-02-10  |  March
  P    |    2     |  222     |  2022-02-15  |  Joy
  S    |    2     |  222     |  2022-02-15  |  Gorge
  P    |    3     |  321     |  2022-02-10  |  Akhil
  P    |    4     |  423     |  2022-02-10  |  Rose
  P    |    5     |  111     |  2022-03-10  |  Addy
  S    |    5     |  111     |  2022-03-10  |  March
  P    |    6     |  111     |  2022-03-08  |  Addy
  S    |    6     |  111     |  2022-03-08  |  March
```

For an example, I need these results:
Here we don't have the duplicate record from date "2022-02-10" & "2022-03-08" of the same HouseNo 111. So here we picked all the HouseNo records with latest date and simultaneous pairs.

```
mType | mindex    | HouseNo  |     date     |   Name
---------------------------------------------------
  P    |    2     |  222     |  2022-02-15  |  Joy
  S    |    2     |  222     |  2022-02-15  |  Gorge
  P    |    3     |  321     |  2022-02-10  |  Akhil
  P    |    4     |  423     |  2022-02-10  |  Rose
  P    |    5     |  111     |  2022-03-10  |  Addy
  S    |    5     |  111     |  2022-03-10  |  March
```

I tried a lot and lastly I came up with this query. Here the `id` is the primary key of the table.  I am using mysql version 5.7.

```
    SELECT
    *
FROM
    `member_details` t
WHERE
    t.id =(
    SELECT
        MAX(t2.id)
    FROM
        member_details t2
    WHERE
        t.name = t2.name AND t.HouseNo = t2.HouseNo
)
```

But here I am unable to pick records which are latest in date. This query give me the last record from the number of duplicate records, making the result. Whereas Addy and March have record with date "2022-03-10" already available in the table.

```
mType | mindex    | HouseNo  |     date     |   Name
---------------------------------------------------
  P    |    2     |  222     |  2022-02-15  |  Joy
  S    |    2     |  222     |  2022-02-15  |  Gorge
  P    |    3     |  321     |  2022-02-10  |  Akhil
  P    |    4     |  423     |  2022-02-10  |  Rose
  P    |    5     |  111     |  2022-03-08  |  Addy
  S    |    5     |  111     |  2022-03-08  |  March
```

Here is the MySQL version on the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `member_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mType` enum('P','S') NOT NULL,
  `mIndex` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `HouseNo` varchar(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `member_details`
--

INSERT INTO `member_details` (`id`, `mType`, `mIndex`, `date`, `Name`, `HouseNo`) VALUES
(1, 'P', 1, '2022-02-10 00:00:00', 'Addy', '111'),
(2, 'S', 1, '2022-02-10 00:00:00', 'Mark', '111'),
(3, 'P', 2, '2022-02-10 00:00:00', 'Joy', '222'),
(4, 'S', 2, '2022-02-10 00:00:00', 'Gorge', '222'),
(5, 'P', 3, '2022-02-10 00:00:00', 'Akhil', '232'),
(6, 'P', 4, '2022-02-10 00:00:00', 'Rose', '324'),
(7, 'P', 5, '2022-03-10 00:00:00', 'Addy', '111'),
(8, 'S', 5, '2022-03-10 00:00:00', 'Mark', '111'),
(9, 'P', 6, '2022-03-08 00:00:00', 'Addy', '111'),
(10, 'S', 6, '2022-03-08 00:00:00', 'Mark', '111');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `member_details`
--
ALTER TABLE `member_details`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: WHERE NOT EXISTS will help. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL is the option too.

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: @Stu I have added my mySql version in the question above

Comment: Where is the version of MySql in your question? What is the column `id` in your query? Edit your question and explain better what you want.

Comment: @forpas `id` is the primary key of the table. I have also mentioned this in the question above.

Comment: Yes you mention id in your question. What you don't mention is why you use it in your query. How is it relevant to your requirement? I can't see it in your sample data. And what is your MySql version?

Comment: *still* not seeing what version of Mysql you're using. I never realised this would be such a challenging request.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by mysql version. Maybe the software version, in that case its 5.7.

Comment: Yes - 5.7 would be the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusingly the sample data inserts you provided are different to the sample data/desired results, however I believe either of the following would work for you - the latter if you can have duplicate dates and need to tie-break on mIndex, using a correlated subquery to filter on the max date per group:

```
select * 
from member_details d
where date = (
  select max(date) from member_details d2 
  where d2.houseno = d.houseno
);

select * 
from member_details d
where date = (
  select date from member_details d2 
  where d2.houseno = d.houseno 
  order by date desc, mIndex desc limit 1
);
```

[See MySql fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c23b0805e253ca530f530af2d5095a22)

Comment: I get it. Surprisingly your query is working on my test table, but not on my actual table with more columns.

Comment: I don't know what *not working* means (errors? unexpected results?) but you can of course ask a new question if you are unable to resolve it, a DBFiddle demonstrating the issue would help greatly.

Comment: I figured my original table is having different "time" in datetime column when I am getting the processed records in the database which is why the query is failing. Can we somehow bind the "S" record followed by the "P" record and then fetch the result as above?